# How to integrate paytm with IONIC 3?

Tags: ionic3

**How to integrate paytm with IONIC 3?**

I have checked paytm development website and also tried many plugins. But could not get any solution. Shall i go for Paytm Checkout for website. Bcoz android SDK or ios SDK will not work in ionic.

Comment: if you have native SDK for Android & iOS you can write your native custom plugin and use it in ionic app refer this link https://medium.com/@sangkhim/build-your-first-cordova-plugin-for-ionic-native-38d29a170145

Answer (score 0):

once try to install this plugin from you ionic project folder using terminal

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-paytm --variable MERCHANT_ID=<MerchantID> --variable INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=<IndustryType> --variable WEBSITE=<WAPWebsiteName> --save
```

then you can continue your process

for your reference go through this site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-paytm